# Cannot retrieve existing param

Tags: ros, parameter, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
It seems I cannot retrieve an existing parameter using roscpp, neither using the node handle nor ros::param. What I want to do is access parameters of a different node. For example, let's consider a node A which wants to read the parameter of a node B, let's say move_base.

So in node A I want to read the parameter /move_base/local_costmap/height, for example. If I use

```
rosparam get /move_base/local_costmap/height
```

I get the value just fine.
If I use in node A's code either

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
std::string param("/move_base/local_costmap/height"), param_value;
n.getParam(param,param_value);
```

or

```
std::string param("/move_base/local_costmap/height"), param_value;
ros::param::get(param,param_value);
```

I do not get the parameter. On the other hand both

```
ros::param::has(param);
```

and

```
nh.hasParam(param);
```

return 1.
I know that this is not the preferred way of accessing other nodes' parameters. But I need it for documentation in a fixed setup. The limitations, .e.g, having to know a node's absolute path, are, in this case, acceptable. Can someone point me in the correct direction how to retrieve the param values or point out other ways how to retrieve parameter values for multiple nodes from one location using roscpp? I'd prefer not to use rosparam as it complicates things.

Thanks for you help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167091/cannot-retrieve-existing-param/) by [torsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/18186/torsten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible that this is failing because the parameter you're trying to retrieve is a double instead of a string?

If you need to handle parameters of unknown type, you may want to either use the xmlrpc variants of the parameter calls in C++, or write your node in python.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [torsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/18186/torsten/) on 2014-05-20**:
Ugh. I've tried pretty much everything concerning paths, handles, etc. But to check for the data type never occurred to me. Thanks.